# Calling a function inside a function and only after it end the rest of the code will happen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native, asynchronous

I want to call first for getUser() function (to check first if there is a user logged in) only then the rest of the function code.

I have a few functions like that, that need the user to be logged in order to happen, and instead of duplicating the code I want to call the getUser() function each time.

The order of the function I need with explanations:

```js
  addComment = () => {

    this.getUser() // check if user is logged with  getItem and setState userOnline boolean

     /// only after the getUser is done will continue with this code - 
    if (this.state.userOnline == true)
    {

    /// fetch and other function code
        this.setState({userOnline : false});
    }

    else {
      
     Alert.alert("You have to be logged-in to publish comments"); 
     return;
        }
     }
```

getUser function -

```js
async getUser() {
    try {
      const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@Ye-Music:user");
      if (user !== null) {
        this.setState({ userData: JSON.parse(user) });
        
        this.setState({ userOnline: true})
      } 
    } catch (error) {}
  }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? please post your getUser() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `addComment` function async if your `getUser()` is async, which it is, considering it is doing `setState()`. Then you need to `await getUser()` before executing the rest of the code.

```
addComment = async () => {
    await getUser();
    //... rest of the code

}
```

Comment: can it can be - async addComment() {  await getUser();
    //... rest of the code
   }    ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to bind it then in constructor. this.addComment = this.addComment.bind(this).

Answer (score 0):

You can use .then because you're using async function. GetUsers is async so it returns a promise. For example:

```
async function f() {
  return 1;
}
f().then(alert);
```

So try this:

```
this.getUser().then(
    if (this.state.userOnline == true)
    {
        /// fetch and other function code
        this.setState({userOnline : false});
    }
    else {
         Alert.alert("You have to be logged-in to publish comments"); 
         return;
    }
 }
)
```